# Why is UncaughtExceptionHandler not called by ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading

I've stumbled upon a problem, that can be summarized as follows:

When I create the thread manually (i.e. by instantiating `java.lang.Thread`) the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is called appropriately. However, when I use an `ExecutorService` with a `ThreadFactory` the handler is ommited. What did I miss?

```
public class ThreadStudy {

private static final int THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // create uncaught exception handler

    final UncaughtExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            synchronized (this) {
                System.err.println("Uncaught exception in thread '" + t.getName() + "': " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    };

    // create thread factory

    ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            // System.out.println("creating pooled thread");
            final Thread thread = new Thread(r);
            thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
            return thread;
        }
    };

    // create Threadpool

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_SIZE, threadFactory);

    // create Runnable

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // System.out.println("A runnable runs...");
            throw new RuntimeException("Error in Runnable");
        }
    };

    // create Callable

    Callable<Integer> callable = new Callable<Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            // System.out.println("A callable runs...");
            throw new Exception("Error in Callable");
        }
    };

    // a) submitting Runnable to threadpool
    threadPool.submit(runnable);

    // b) submit Callable to threadpool
    threadPool.submit(callable);

    // c) create a thread for runnable manually
    final Thread thread_r = new Thread(runnable, "manually-created-thread");
    thread_r.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(exceptionHandler);
    thread_r.start();

    threadPool.shutdown();
    System.out.println("Done.");
}
}
```

I expect: Three times the message "Uncaught exception..."

I get: The message once (triggered by the manually created thread).

Reproduced with Java 1.6 on Windows 7 and Mac OS X 10.5.

Comment: Maybe this work, for me it's ok It is not a FixedThreadPool, but SingleThreadPool... but you get the idea http://stackoverflow.com/a/44007121/8020889

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Because the exception does not go uncaught.

The Thread that your ThreadFactory produces is not given your Runnable or Callable directly. Instead, the Runnable that you get is an internal Worker class, for example see ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker. Try `System.out.println()` on the Runnable given to newThread in your example.

This Worker catches any RuntimeExceptions from your submitted job.

You can get the exception in the [ThreadPoolExecutor#afterExecute](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#afterExecute(java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.Throwable)) method.

Comment: Although this answer is correct, properly implementing afterExecute is tricky. See [this overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks) for an example of how to properly implement the solution suggested here.

Comment: Here's an article on exception-handling in threaded code, including `Future` and `ExecutorService`: http://literatejava.com/threading/silent-thread-death-unhandled-exceptions/

Comment: This answer is not exactly correct. The reason the UncaughtExceptionHandler doesn't work as expected is not because the internal worker swallows exceptions.

The reason it doesn't work is because submit is being used which means that a future is being created and the task is run in the future.

Instead of implementing the more complex afterExecute you can simply take the future returned from the submit call and do a whenComplete call to process the exception.

You will see your expected log in the above code if you run threadPool.execute(runnable) instead of submit.

Answer (score 48):

Exceptions which are thrown by tasks submitted to `ExecutorService#submit` get wrapped into an `ExcecutionException` and are rethrown by the `Future.get()` method. This is, because the executor considers the exception as part of the result of the task.

If you however submit a task via the `execute()` method which originates from the `Executor` interface, the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is notified.

Comment: This is a surprisingly clean and easy solution. Thanks!

Comment: By far the easiest solution. 
More info on that behavior in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3986509/2874005

Comment: In my experiments, if the `ExecutorService` has been shutdown, and its last surviving worker thread encounters an uncaught exception, it seems to terminate before invoking the handler. I can't see from the `ThreadPoolExecutor` why this would be so though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that exception handling differs fundamentally between `submit()` and `execute()`. It's logical when you think about it, but very surprising at first glance. Since `execute()` is not defined in `ExecutorService`, but in its superinterface `Executor`, it is easily overlooked when browsing through JavaDoc. There are probably a lot of cases out there where `submit()` is being used but `execute()` would have been correct.

Answer (score 36):

Quote from the book *Java Concurrency in Practice*(page 163),hope this helps

> Somewhat confusingly, exceptions thrown from tasks make it to the uncaught
>   exception handler only for tasks submitted with execute; for tasks submitted
>   with submit, any thrown exception, checked or not, is considered to be part of the
>   task’s return status. If a task submitted with submit terminates with an exception,
>   it is rethrown by Future.get, wrapped in an ExecutionException.

Here is the example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){


    ThreadFactory factory = new ThreadFactory(){

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final Thread thread =new Thread(r);

            thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler( new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("in exception handler");
                }
            });

            return thread;
        }

    };

    ExecutorService pool=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(factory);
    pool.execute(new testTask());

}



private static class TestTask implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

}
```

I use execute to submit the task and the console outputs "in exception handler"

Comment: Better to rename class `testTask` to `TestTask`.

Comment: @JasonLaw Forgive my typo, fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I just browsed through my old questions and thought I might share the solution I implemented in case it helps someone (or I missed a bug).

```
import java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.RunnableScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


/**
 * @author Mike Herzog, 2009
 */
public class ExceptionHandlingExecuterService extends ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor {

    /** My ExceptionHandler */
    private final UncaughtExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    /**
     * Encapsulating a task and enable exception handling.
     * <p>
     * <i>NB:</i> We need this since {@link ExecutorService}s ignore the
     * {@link UncaughtExceptionHandler} of the {@link ThreadFactory}.
     * 
     * @param <V> The result type returned by this FutureTask's get method.
     */
    private class ExceptionHandlingFutureTask<V> extends FutureTask<V> implements RunnableScheduledFuture<V> {

        /** Encapsulated Task */
        private final RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task;

        /**
         * Encapsulate a {@link Callable}.
         * 
         * @param callable
         * @param task
         */
        public ExceptionHandlingFutureTask(Callable<V> callable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
            super(callable);
            this.task = task;
        }

        /**
         * Encapsulate a {@link Runnable}.
         * 
         * @param runnable
         * @param result
         * @param task
         */
        public ExceptionHandlingFutureTask(Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
            super(runnable, null);
            this.task = task;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * @see java.util.concurrent.FutureTask#done() The actual exception
         * handling magic.
         */
        @Override
        protected void done() {
            // super.done(); // does nothing
            try {
                get();

            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                if (exceptionHandler != null) {
                    exceptionHandler.uncaughtException(null, e.getCause());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // never mind cancelation or interruption...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isPeriodic() {
            return this.task.isPeriodic();
        }

        @Override
        public long getDelay(TimeUnit unit) {
            return task.getDelay(unit);
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Delayed other) {
            return task.compareTo(other);
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param corePoolSize The number of threads to keep in the pool, even if
     *        they are idle.
     * @param eh Receiver for unhandled exceptions. <i>NB:</i> The thread
     *        reference will always be <code>null</code>.
     */
    public ExceptionHandlingExecuterService(int corePoolSize, UncaughtExceptionHandler eh) {
        super(corePoolSize);
        this.exceptionHandler = eh;
    }

    @Override
    protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Callable<V> callable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
        return new ExceptionHandlingFutureTask<V>(callable, task);
    }

    @Override
    protected <V> RunnableScheduledFuture<V> decorateTask(Runnable runnable, RunnableScheduledFuture<V> task) {
        return new ExceptionHandlingFutureTask<V>(runnable, task);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Thilos answer: I've written a post about this behavior, if one wants to have it explained a little bit more verbose: https://ewirch.github.io/2013/12/a-executor-is-not-a-thread.html.

Here is a excerpts from the article:

> A Thread is capable of processing only one Runable in general. When the Thread.run() method exits the Thread dies. The ThreadPoolExecutor implements a trick to make a Thread process multiple Runnables: it uses a own Runnable implementation. The threads are being started with a Runnable implementation which fetches other Runanbles (your Runnables) from the ExecutorService and executes them: ThreadPoolExecutor -> Thread -> Worker -> YourRunnable. When a uncaught exception occurs in your Runnable implementation it ends up in the finally block of Worker.run(). In this finally block the Worker class tells the ThreadPoolExecutor that it “finished” the work. The exception did not yet arrive at the Thread class but ThreadPoolExecutor already registered the worker as idle.
>
> And here’s where the fun begins. The awaitTermination() method will be invoked when all Runnables have been passed to the Executor. This happens very quickly so that probably not one of the Runnables finished their work. A Worker will switch to “idle” if a exception occurs, before the Exception reaches the Thread class. If the situation is similar for the other threads (or if they finished their work), all Workers signal “idle” and awaitTermination() returns. The main thread reaches the code line where it checks the size of the collected exception list. And this may happen before any (or some) of the Threads had the chance to call the UncaughtExceptionHandler. It depends on the order of execution if or how many exceptions will be added to the list of uncaught exceptions, before the main thread reads it.
>
> A very unexpected behavior. But I won’t leave you without a working solution. So let’s make it work.
>
> We are lucky that the ThreadPoolExecutor class was designed for extensibility. There is a empty protected method afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t). This will be invoked directly after the run() method of our Runnable before the worker signals that it finished the work. The correct solution is to extend the ThreadPoolExecutor to handle uncaught exceptions:
>
> ```
>  public class ExceptionAwareThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {
>      private final List<Throwable> uncaughtExceptions = 
>                      Collections.synchronizedList(new LinkedList<Throwable>());
>
>      @Override
>      protected void afterExecute(final Runnable r, final Throwable t) {
>          if (t != null) uncaughtExceptions.add(t);
>      }
>
>      public List<Throwable> getUncaughtExceptions() {
>          return Collections.unmodifiableList(uncaughtExceptions);
>      }
>  }
> ```

Comment: Might be good to add some details from that post here too! :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a little bit of a workaround.
In your `run` method, you can catch every exception, and later on do something like this (ex: in a `finally` block)

```
Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), ex);
//or, same effect:
Thread.currentThread().getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(Thread.currentThread(), ex);
```

This will "ensure a firing" of the current exception as thrown to your uncoughtExceptionHandler (or to the defualt uncought exception handler). 
You can always rethrow catched exceptions for pool worker.