# How is exception handling done in a Callable

Tags: java, multithreading

I understand that callable's call can throw the exception to the parent method calling it which is not the case with runnable.

I wonder how because it's a thread method and is the bottommost method of the thread stack.

Comment: I'm not sure about what's your question. Is it about the implementation of classes rethrowing an exception throwed by a Callable ?

Comment: No. My simple doubt is that when callable throws an exception who catches it. And if an exception in call method of Callable can be thrown then why not run of Runnable throw an exception

Comment: Runnable is run in a separate thread (hence the name).  Callable isn't (hence the name).  In fact, you CAN throw an exception out of a Runnable, but there's nothing to handle it (other than the JVM's "shoot me" handler).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The point of [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) is to have your exception thrown to your calling thread, for example when you get the result of a `Future` to which you submitted your `callable`.

```
public class CallableClass implements Callable<String> {
...
}

ExecutorService executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(5);
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(callable);

try {
    System.out.println(future.get());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar The `submit` function in `executor` does support `Callable`s

Answer (score 6):

`Callable.call()` **can't** be the bottommost stack frame. It's always called by another method that will then catch the exception. `Callable` should usually be used to asynchronously compute values and later get them with a `Future` object. The operation *might* throw an exception that is later rethrown when you try to get the `Future`'s value.

`Runnable` is simply supposed to run an operation that doesn't return anything. All exception handling should be done within the `Runnable` because it's unclear how any exceptions thrown in `Runnable.run()` should be handled. (The exception from a `Callable` is usually returned to the caller with the `Future`)

Comment: May I know which method catches callable exception coz as per my understanding,callable is called when a thread is started and call is the first method to occupy the call stack.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user1649415 As I am saying in my answer `Callable.call()` **can't** be the first method to occupy the call stack. It's always called somewhere else and if it throws an exception that exception is usually caught and later rethrown if you try to get the `Future`'s value.