# How to handle exception thrown by an ExecutorService task?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I'm using an ExecutorService to run tests upon a system. The problem arises when a test fails for some reason. These reason can be a many, and of course I'm logging these errors.

But I would like to, in real-time, notify the user of an error. So when an error occurs, the longer it reaches the top, it becomes a `TestFailedException` with a message and a cause. I would like to catch this exception and notify the user, but I can't seem to do that.

This is an example of a method that is actually starting the thread that runs the test:

```
public void asyncRunTestfixture(Concretetest concretetest) {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    FutureTask<Boolean> futureTask_1 = new FutureTask<Boolean>(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws TestFailedException {
            return RunTestInFixture(concretetest);          
        }

      });
      executor.execute(futureTask_1);
      executor.shutdown(); 
}
```

But even though call throws an exception, I can't catch it elsewhere, neither now or if I say the asyncRunTestfixture methods throws an exception.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The exception will be thrown to you when you call `futureTask_1.get()` to get the result. It will be wrapped inside an `ExecutionException`.

Comment: Refer this answer from another [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305667/how-is-exception-handling-done-in-a-callable)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, the exception is thrown when it is thrown.  The exception is _caught_ by the pool worker thread, and the handler stores a refernce to the exception object in the `Future`.  Finally, the `ExecutionException` is thrown when the client calls the future's `get()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `get()` on the completed `futureTask_1` will throw an `ExecutionException` typically wrapping the `cause` when the task threw some exception.

Comment: Of course -  I did that other places. Simply didn't think of doing it here - duh! :) Thanks! Works perfectly.

Comment: Which will make the hole thing synchronous.