# Where to catch Exceptions thrown from Callable.call()

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice, callable

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Handling exceptions from Java ExecutorService tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks)

I use the `ExecutorService` from Java for coordinating Threads.
For starting the threads I use

```
pool = new ExecutorService(2);
callableResults = pool.invokeAll(threads);
```

To collect the result, I use `future.get()` for each thread.
"threads" is a List of Objects from a Class which implements `Callable` and overrides `call()`.

Now Ive got the following problem. The method `call()` does throw various specific exceptions. `invokeAll()` and `future.get()` throw only `InterruptedException`.

Where can I catch my specific exceptions which I throw in `call()`? Or do I have to handle them there? If one of those exceptions is thrown, is the result then a `InterruptedException`?

Comment: I read this before, but I did not see that he uses Callable and call() as well? Maybe Ive overseen it!? edit: correct. Ive overseen it. sorry.

Comment: In this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2248166/118846

Comment: He uses Runnable but the exception catching is the same.

Comment: `Future.get()` throws `InterruptedException` *and* `ExecutionException`. You need to read the javadocs more carefully.

Comment: The *answer* (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2248166/302916) does.

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I only saw the InterruptedException.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

AFAIR [`java.util.concurrent.Future.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()) will throw [`ExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) if provided callable threw exception in the past (the exception is stored in the `Future`).

> Exception thrown when attempting to retrieve the result of a task that aborted by throwing an exception. **This exception can be inspected using the `Throwable.getCause()` method**.

Comment: The very reason to use `ExecutorService` is its ability to run without blocking. `get()`, on the other hand, is blocking until the task is executed. Seems like this is one of the major drawbacks of `ExecutorService`