# How to get an Exception from Task runing in ExecutorService?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, executorservice

I have a class A that implements Runnable interface, this class perform my batch job. Their is a controller class which is responsible for creating ExecutorService and submitting objects of Class A to ExecutorService instance in a for loop.

I want to terminated the execution of all task, if any task execution encounters exception as their is high probability that the exception will be caused in all task and I want the cause to be thrown to caller code.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there is no magic on offer in the Jdk to mangage the cancellataion of the tasks (after a problem in another sibling thread). Looks like you need to keep track of the Future instances and manage the cancellation yourself.

Or find a library that has done the work for you. It might be worth investigating if Spring Batch supports this kind of case.