# Schedule exceptions in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, quartz-scheduler

I'm developing a task that requires downloading files from given URLs, one of the requirement is that it could handle network failures and exceptions.

In my implementation I had a DonwloadManager that assigns a thread for every URL, so as not to be blocking.

The problem is that I am not sure how to mock failures and exceptions through the code, I tried using Quartz as scheduler and a job that only throws exception, but as far as I know the scheduler runs on different thread, so this won't affect the downloading thread at all.

Is there a way to mock the exceptions within the downloading thread ?

Here is my code for more insights:

```
public class DownloadManager {

int allocatedMemory = 0;

void validateURLs(String[] urls) {
    if (urls.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("URLs List is empty");
    }
}

public ArrayList<Status> downloadURLs(String[] urls, int memorySize) throws Exception {
    validateURLs(urls);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newWorkStealingPool();
    CompletionService<Status> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Status>(executor);
    ArrayList<Status> downloadStatus = new ArrayList<Status>();
    allocatedMemory = memorySize / urls.length;
    for (String url : urls) {
       completionService.submit(new DownloadWorker(url, allocatedMemory));
    }
    for(int i=0;i<urls.length;i++){
       Future<Status> URLStatus =  completionService.take();
        System.out.println(URLStatus.get());
        downloadStatus.add(URLStatus.get());
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    return downloadStatus;
}
```

And this is the download Worker:

```
class DownloadWorker implements Callable<Status> {

static final int SUCCESS = 1, FAILURE = 0;

private int bufferSize;

private String assignedURL;

public DownloadWorker(String assignedURL, int bufferSize) {
    this.bufferSize = bufferSize;
    this.assignedURL = assignedURL;
}

public Status call() throws Exception {
    URLConnection openConnection = new URL(assignedURL).openConnection();
    openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0");
    String outputFileName = assignedURL.substring(assignedURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
    RandomAccessFile outputFile = new RandomAccessFile(outputFileName, "rw");
    ReadableByteChannel inputChannel = Channels.newChannel(openConnection.getInputStream());
    FileChannel outputChannel = outputFile.getChannel();
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bufferSize);
    while (inputChannel.read(buffer) > 0) {
        buffer.flip();
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.limit(); i++) {
            outputChannel.write(buffer);
        }
        buffer.clear();
    }
    outputChannel.close();
    inputChannel.close();
    outputFile.close();
    return new Status(assignedURL, true);
}
```

}

Any suggestions on how to mock/test the exception programmatically ?

Update: I was thinking, instead of scheduling exceptions, it would be easier to mock the resulting Future status, so that it returns an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `DownloadWorker`, sleep for 6 seconds and when you are getting a `Future` in `DownloadManager` thread, set `timeout` as 5 seconds. Now you will get `timeout` exception.

In this way, list out `Exceptions` you want to catch in `DownloadManager` thread and throw them from your `DownloadWorker`.

Other way is overriding `ThredPoolExecutor` after execute method as per this one:

[Handling exceptions from Java ExecutorService tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks)

Note that `FutureTask`s swallows the exceptions (if you use submit() instead of execute() on `ExecutorService`. Have a look at source [code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.java#FutureTask.Sync.innerRun%28%29). So raise exceptions properly from `DownloadWorker`.

Answer (score 0):

java executors is another option  (see [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html))

- you can use the awaitTermination method in executor to wait in the current thread for all tasks to finish
- check the Future (element returned when you submit) for exceptions