# How do we come to know that the thread has finished its execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-7

I am using ExecutorService. Following is the code

```
public class A{ 
   public static void main(String args[]){
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        Runnable worker = new FileUploadThread("thread");
        executorService.execute(worker);
   } 
}

public class FileuploadThread extends Thread{
    //has a parametrized constuctor

     @Override
     public void run(){
        for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
            syso("executing...");
        }
     }
}
```

I want to receive an event or something in the main method when the thread completes it task. How can i do that ?

Comment: Use `Callable` and return a value. Then `Future#get` can be used.

Comment: Can you show me how ? or point out a link that i can refer ?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callable-future-java/

Comment: The declaration should be `FileuploadThread implements Runnable` instead of `FileuploadThread extends Thread`. It’s a mistake to allocate the resources of a `Thread` when you actually just need a `Runnable` (and a big mistake of the Java designers to let `Thread` implement `Runnable` leading to such mistakes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To know about the task status - You need Future instance.
Now there are two points:

1. If you are just interested to know whether the task has been completed or not, Use `executorService.submit(worker)` , instead of `executorService.execute(worker)` method.
2. If you also want to get some result back after the task completion, Use `Callable` interface instead of `Runnable`. See below code:

   ```
   public class A {
     public static void main(String args[]){
       ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
       Callable<String> worker = new FileUploadThread("thread");
       Future<String> workerTask = executorService.submit(worker);

       try {
           boolean isDone = workerTask.isDone();
           System.out.println("Task is done: " + isDone);

           //Wait untill task is executing
           String status = workerTask.get();

           System.out.println("Status: " + status);
           isDone = workerTask.isDone();
           System.out.println("Task is done: " + isDone);
       } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       executorService.shutdown();
     }
   }

   class FileUploadThread implements Callable<String> {
     //has a parametrized constuctor
     public FileUploadThread(String thread) { }

     @Override
     public String call() throws Exception {
       for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
           System.out.println("executing..sleep for 1 sec...");
           Thread.sleep(1000);
       }
       return "DONE";
     }
   }
   ```

**Output:**

```
Task is done: false
executing..sleep for 1 sec...
executing..sleep for 1 sec...
executing..sleep for 1 sec...
executing..sleep for 1 sec...
executing..sleep for 1 sec...
Status: DONE
Task is done: true
```

Comment: statement 
workerTask.get(); 
does this method actually waits for the thread execution? if an exeception arise in the thread how it will be handled ?

Comment: Yes. It does.  It is explained in the javadoc.  Exceptions are explained there too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks        for those who require the link to handle exceptions

Comment: @Pri_stack Just to note, you don't _have_ to switch to `Callable` in order to get a `Future`, assuming you don't need a result. There's the [`ExecutorService#submit(Runnable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) overload.

Answer (score 0):

When you `start` a thread with **yourThread.start()**, the system starts a new thread doing what is inside the `run` method. You can simply print something like this : `System.out.println("FINISHED " + this.getName())` at the end of the `run` method.

**PS** : please make sure you don't place the print above in some loops, it should be the last statement in the `run` method. ( The .execute() method is **almost** the same thing with .start() )

Answer (score 0):

You could use `yourThread.join()`.