# How Thread Life Cycle works inside Thread Pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Could anyone explain how thread life cycle works inside thread pool.Is it same as normal thread life cycle?

Comment: Do you actually meant to tag j, as in the j programming language by jsoftware? They're entirely different from the Java programming language

Comment: Sorry i accidentally tagged j Edited my tags.Thanks!

Comment: A thread is a thread, whether it's in a pool or not. The thread pool creates the thread when necessary, the thread waits for a task by, for example, blocking on a queue until either a task arrives, in which case the thread executes the task and goes back to waiting for another task, or the configured "max idle time" / "keep alive time" expires and the pool lets the thread die. Each thread in the pool is doing this in parallel (typically using the same queue).

Answer (score 2):

1. ThreadPool can wrap your Runnable/Callable with Future*(if you use submit() method)
2. Runnable/Callable faces with task queue and saturation policy

   - behaviour depends on:

     - number of active threads in pool
     - corePoolSize
     - maximumPoolSize
     - saturation of queue
     - saturation policy(default is AbortPolicy)
3. ThreadFactory creates Thread. Can be configured:

   - set UncaughtExceptionHandler
   - set name of Thread
   - set daemon flag
4. beforeExecute() - empty hook method, you can override it
5. Running your Thread
6. afterExecute()** - empty hook method, you can override it
7. Thread may be terminated or waits for processing new task. Configured by allowCoreThreadTimeOut()

* using submit() method changes code for afterExecute() - [Handling exceptions from Java ExecutorService tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks)
**afterExecute() will be not invoked if beforeExecute() throw any Exception

Note: part of behaviour of thread pool is similar to pattern template method - beforeExecute() -> run() -> afterExecute().