# Scala Futures are silently dropping Exceptions by default - can I change this?

Tags: scala, future

I've only found old threads regarding this where all proposed solutions look like hacks to me, like adding "recoverwith" to every future manually everywhere.
I want my scala futures to always have a default onComplete handler that logs the exception. Otherwise, exceptions get silently dropped by default, and that is a bad default behaviour.

Comment: Create an ExecutionContext from an execution service that does logging of exceptions. And use it in all of your futures. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks

Comment: I'm not experienced enough to know if this is a valid answer or not.  But why doesn't anyone suggest Zio for problems like this?