# How to fail JUnit test from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, junit

Consider following test code:

```java
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
        latch.countDown();
        Assert.fail("Doesn't fail the test");
    });

    latch.await();
}
```

It prints exception, but passes.

> Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.AssertionError:
> Doesn't fail the test at
> org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89) at
> MyTest.lambda$test$0(MyTest.java:55) at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at
> java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

I have tried to set custom uncaught exception handler `setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> Assert.fail(e.getMessage()))`, but this didn't help.

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish with running tests this way? I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2248203/12092416) might help though I don't understand completely what result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an external state that both threads can access. Please note `latch.countDown();` should be added after you changed the state

```
    private volatile boolean failed  = false;
    
    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        var latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
            failed = true;//or false depending on the use case
            latch.countDown();
            
        });

        latch.await();
        if(failed){
            Assert.fail("Doesn't fail the test");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use shutdown + awaitTermination to make sure all tasks are finished and use a try-catch and an AtomicBoolean to assert no AssertionErrors were raised "inside".

```
AtomicBoolean failed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(PARALLEL_POOL_SIZE);

// start tasks.. maybe in a loop to generate load..
executorService.execute(() -> {
  try {
    // Test something
    // ..
    // Validate
    assertThat(actual, equalTo(EXPECTED));
  } catch (AssertionError e) {
    failed.set(true);
    throw e;
  }
});

executorService.shutdown();
boolean terminatedInTime = executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
assertTrue(terminatedInTime);
assertFalse(failed.get());
```

Comment: Thank you for the creative input, that really helped me :)