# Choose between ExecutorService's submit and ExecutorService's execute

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

How should I choose between **ExecutorService's** [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit-java.util.concurrent.Callable-) or [execute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-), if the returned value is not my concern?

If I test both, I didn't see any differences among the two except the returned value.

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
threadExecutor.execute(new Task());
```

---

```
ExecutorService threadExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
threadExecutor.submit(new Task());
```

Answer (score 220, accepted):

There is a difference concerning exception/error handling.

A task queued with `execute()` that generates some `Throwable` will cause the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` for the `Thread` running the task to be invoked. The default `UncaughtExceptionHandler`, which typically prints the `Throwable` stack trace to `System.err`, will be invoked if no custom handler has been installed.

On the other hand, a `Throwable` generated by a task queued with `submit()` will bind the `Throwable` to the `Future` that was produced from the call to `submit()`. Calling `get()` on that `Future` will throw an `ExecutionException` with the original `Throwable` as its cause (accessible by calling `getCause()` on the `ExecutionException`).

Comment: Note that this behaviour is not guaranteed as it is dependent on whether or not your `Runnable` gets wrapped in a `Task` or not, which you may have no control over. For example, if your `Executor` is actually a `ScheduledExecutorService`, your task will internally get wrapped in a `Future` and uncaught `Throwable`s will be bound to this object.

Comment: I mean 'wrapped in a `Future` or not', of course. See the Javadoc for [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor#execute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)), for example.

Comment: And what happens to the thread in executor service? Ex: If we have fixed thread executor with 10 numbers and exception is thrown, will a new thread be replaced and still have 10 threads? Also any difference between submit and execute in this context?

Answer (score 70):

***execute***: Use it for fire and forget calls

From [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) by **docs.oracle.com**

***submit:***

> Method submit extends base method Executor.execute(Runnable) by creating and returning a Future that can be used to cancel execution and/or wait for completion

`submit(Callable<T> task)`

> Submits a value-returning task for execution and returns a Future
> representing the pending results of the task.

`Future<?> submit(Runnable task)`

> Submits a Runnable task for execution and returns a Future representing that
> task.

```
void execute(Runnable command)
```

> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

You have to take precaution while using `submit()`. It hides exception in the framework itself unless you embed your task code in `try{} catch{}` block.

**Example code:** This code swallows `Arithmetic exception : / by zero`.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ExecuteSubmitDemo{
    public ExecuteSubmitDemo()
    {
        System.out.println("creating service");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        //ExtendedExecutor service = new ExtendedExecutor();
        service.submit(new Runnable(){
                 public void run(){
                    int a=4, b = 0;
                    System.out.println("a and b="+a+":"+b);
                    System.out.println("a/b:"+(a/b));
                    System.out.println("Thread Name in Runnable after divide by zero:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                 }
            });
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ExecuteSubmitDemo demo = new ExecuteSubmitDemo();
    }
}
```

output:

```
java ExecuteSubmitDemo
creating service
a and b=4:0
```

Same code throws by replacing `submit()` with `execute`() :

Replace

```
service.submit(new Runnable(){
```

with

```
service.execute(new Runnable(){
```

output:

```
java ExecuteSubmitDemo
creating service
a and b=4:0
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
        at ExecuteSubmitDemo$1.run(ExecuteSubmitDemo.java:14)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

***How to handle the these type of scenarios while using submit()?***

1. Embed your Task code ( *Either Runnable or Callable implementation) with try{} catch{} block code*
2. Implement `CustomThreadPoolExecutor` as explained in [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) by **docs.oracle.com** with `ExtendedExecutor` class handling `afterExecute` method

**New solution:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ExecuteSubmitDemo{
    public ExecuteSubmitDemo()
    {
        System.out.println("creating service");
        //ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        /* Refer to linked Oracle documentation page for ExtendedExecutor  source code */
        ExtendedExecutor service = new ExtendedExecutor();
        service.submit(new Runnable(){
                 public void run(){
                    int a=4, b = 0;
                    System.out.println("a and b="+a+":"+b);
                    System.out.println("a/b:"+(a/b));
                    System.out.println("Thread Name in Runnable after divide by zero:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                 }
            });
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ExecuteSubmitDemo demo = new ExecuteSubmitDemo();
    }
}
```

output:

```
java ExecuteSubmitDemo
creating service
a and b=4:0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Comment: Good crisp explanation. Although extending it NOT really required. Just that future object has to be consumed in order to know whether the task was success or not.  thus, use submit() if you are planning to consume Future<t>  otherwise simply use execute()

Answer (score 13):

if you dont care about the return type, use execute. it's the same as submit, just without the return of Future.

Comment: This is not correct according to the accepted answer. Exception handling is a pretty significant difference.

Answer (score 8):

Taken from the Javadoc:

> Method `submit` extends base method {@link Executor#`execute`} by creating and 
>   returning a {@link Future} that can be used to cancel execution and/or wait for 
>   completion.

Personally I prefer the use of execute because it feels more declarative, although this really is a matter of personal preference.

To give more information: in the case of the `ExecutorService` implementation, the core implementation being returned by the call to `Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor()` is a `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

The `submit` calls are provided by its parent `AbstractExecutorService` and all call execute internally. execute is overridden/provided by the `ThreadPoolExecutor` directly.

Answer (score 5):

The full answer is a composition of two answers that were published here (plus a bit "extra"):

- By submitting a task (vs. executing it) you get back a future which can be used to get the result or cancel the action. You don't have this kind of control when you `execute` (because its return type id `void`)
- `execute` expects a `Runnable` while `submit` can take either a `Runnable` or a `Callable` as an argument (for more info about the difference between the two - see below).
- `execute` bubbles up any unchecked-exceptions right away (it cannot throw checked exceptions!!!), while `submit` binds *any* kind of exception to the future that returns as a result, and only when you call `future.get()` a the (wrapped) exception will be thrown . The Throwable that you'll get is an instance of `ExecutionException` and if you'll call this object's `getCause()` it will return the original Throwable.

A few more (related) points:

- Even if the task that you want to `submit` does not require returning a
  result, you can still use `Callable<Void>` (instead of using a `Runnable`).
- Cancellation of tasks can be done using the [interrupt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) mechanism. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6599544/1057429) of how to implement a cancellation policy

To sum up, it's a better practice to use `submit` with a `Callable` (vs. `execute` with a `Runnable`). And I'll quote from "Java concurrency in practice" By Brian Goetz:

> **6.3.2 Result-bearing tasks: Callable and Future**
>
> The Executor framework uses Runnable as its basic task representation. Runnable is a fairly
>   limiting abstraction; run cannot return a value or throw checked
>   exceptions, although it can have side effects such as writing to a log
>   file or placing a result in a shared data structure. Many tasks are
>   effectively deferred computations—executing a database query, fetching
>   a resource over the network, or computing a complicated function. For
>   these types of tasks, Callable is a better abstraction: it expects
>   that the main entry point, call, will return a value and anticipates
>   that it might throw an exception.7 Executors includes several utility
>   methods for wrapping other types of tasks, including Runnable and
>   java.security.PrivilegedAction, with a Callable.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-):

> The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, or in the calling thread, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

So depending on the implementation of `Executor` you may find that the submitting thread blocks while the task is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to the accepted answer-

> However, exceptions thrown from tasks make it to the uncaught
>   exception handler only for tasks submitted with execute(); for tasks
>   submitted with submit() to the executor service, any thrown exception
>   is considered to be part of the task’s return status.

[Source](https://medium.com/@aozturk/how-to-handle-uncaught-exceptions-in-java-abf819347906)