# ThreadPoolExecutor - differences between submit and execute methods?

Tags: java, threadpool

I faced a problem about `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

After writing some code, I found the `submit()` method will eat the `RuntimeException` thrown by the program, but the `execute()` method will re-throw the RuntimeException`. I want to know the reason for this.

I recently read the source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor` and know the principle of a thread pool. 
Now I understand how `execute()` method executes, but I couldn't understand how `submit()` method executes. I only know that the `submit()` method will wrap the `Runnable` or `Callable` in a `FutureTask` and call the `execute()` method:

```
public Future submit(Runnable runnable)
{
    if(runnable == null)
    {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    } else
    {
        RunnableFuture runnablefuture = newTaskFor(runnable, null);
        execute(runnablefuture);
        return runnablefuture;
    }
}
```

So, my problem is: how does `ThreadPoolExecutor` execute `FutureTask` and why is the `RuntimeException` eaten?

Comment: a good explanation is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342/choose-between-executorservices-submit-and-executorservices-execute

Comment: I know the submit() method will bind the exception to Future,but after reading the source code of ThreadPoolExecutor,I didn't find the place where it did? So I want to know how the submit() method bind the exception to Future?

Comment: answered with explanation

Answer (score 0):

If you look into `newTaskFor` method you'll see that `RunnableFuture` is in fact instance of `java.util.concurrent.FutureTask`. You should see the `run` method in this FutureTask class.

```
public void run() {
    sync.innerRun();
}
```

and here is the innerRun method:

```
    void innerRun() {
        if (!compareAndSetState(READY, RUNNING))
            return;

        runner = Thread.currentThread();
        if (getState() == RUNNING) { // recheck after setting thread
            V result;
            try {
                result = callable.call();
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                setException(ex);
                return;
            }
            set(result);
        } else {
            releaseShared(0); // cancel
        }
    }
```

the exception is caught and set to task. It will be thrown wrapped into ExecutionException when you call get method of FutureTask

```
 public V get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    return sync.innerGet();
}
```

Comment: thank you. I find the answer, in the method runTask(Runnable runnable) of ThreadPoolExecutor, runnable.run() will be called, so the run method of the runnale or the fufureTask will be called.

Comment: I explained to you the difference between submit and execute. I thought that that's what you asked for and how exception is eaten