# What is the difference between ExecutorService.submit and ExecutorService.execute in this code in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am learning to use `ExectorService` to pool `threads` and send out tasks. I have a simple program below

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


class Processor implements Runnable {

    private int id;

    public Processor(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting: " + id);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("sorry, being interupted, good bye!");
            System.out.println("Interrupted " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Completed: " + id);
    }
}


public class ExecutorExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Boolean isCompleted = false;

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            executor.execute(new Processor(i));
        }

        //executor does not accept any more tasks but the submitted tasks continue
        executor.shutdown();

        System.out.println("All tasks submitted.");

        try {
            //wait for the exectutor to terminate normally, which will return true
            //if timeout happens, returns false, but this does NOT interrupt the threads
            isCompleted = executor.awaitTermination(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //this will interrupt thread it manages. catch the interrupted exception in the threads
            //If not, threads will run forever and executor will never be able to shutdown.
            executor.shutdownNow();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        if (isCompleted) {
            System.out.println("All tasks completed.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Timeout " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }
}
```

It does nothing fancy, but creates two `threads` and submits 5 tasks in total. After each `thread` completes its task, it takes the next one,
In the code above, I use `executor.submit`. I also changed to `executor.execute`. But I do not see any difference in the output. In what way are the `submit` and `execute` methods different?
This what the `API` says

> Method submit extends base method Executor.execute(java.lang.Runnable) by creating and returning a Future that can be used to cancel execution and/or wait for completion. Methods invokeAny and invokeAll perform the most commonly useful forms of bulk execution, executing a collection of tasks and then waiting for at least one, or all, to complete. (Class ExecutorCompletionService can be used to write customized variants of these methods.)

But it's not clear to me as what it exactly means?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As you see from the JavaDoc `execute(Runnable)` does not return anything.

However, `submit(Callable<T>)` returns a `Future` object which allows a way for you to programatically cancel the running thread later as well as get the `T` that is returned when the `Callable` completes. See [JavaDoc of Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) for more details

```
Future<?> future = executor.submit(longRunningJob);
...
//long running job is taking too long
future.cancel(true);
```

Moreover,
if `future.get() == null` and doesn't throw any exception then Runnable executed successfully

Comment: Just to add-> It can't cancel once the thread has picked up the task. Though it'll interrupt the threading running it.

Comment: Another difference is that if the job that is run with `execute(...)` throws an exception, the thread will be killed in the process and possibly then restarted by the `ExecutorService`.

Answer (score 59):

The difference is that `execute` simply starts the task without any further ado, whereas `submit` returns a `Future` object to manage the task. You can do the following things with the `Future` object:

- Cancel the task prematurely, with the `cancel` method.
- Wait for the task to finish executing, with `get`.

The `Future` interface is more useful if you submit a `Callable` to the pool. The return value of the `call` method will be returned when you call `Future.get`. If you don't maintain a reference to the `Future`, there is no difference.

Comment: No, the execute() specification says "Executes the given command at some time in the future". So, it's not necessarily started immediately. The difference is that you don't care when it's executed or to check things like a result or completion.

Answer (score 39):

`execute:` Use it for fire and forget calls

`submit:`  Use it to cancel execution and/or wait for completion on created `Future` object

Major difference: `Exception` handling

`submit()` hides un-handled `Exception` in framework itself.

`execute()` throws un-handled `Exception`.

Solution for handling Exceptions with `submit()`

1. Wrap your `Callable or Runnable code in try{} catch{} block`

   OR
2. Keep `future.get() call in try{} catch{} block`

   OR
3. implement your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` and override `afterExecute` method

Related post with code example:

[Choose between ExecutorService's submit and ExecutorService's execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342/choose-between-executorservices-submit-and-executorservices-execute/35424481#35424481)

`Future.get()` transforms your asynchronus execution to synchronous execution and you won't get benefits of asynchronous execution.

If your business use cases revolves around asynchronous event processing and you expect responsiveness in X seconds, you can timeout on Future operation.

Regarding tour other queries on

[invokeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll-java.util.Collection-):

> Executes the given tasks, returning a list of Futures holding their status and results when all complete or the timeout expires, whichever happens first.

[invokeAny](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAny-java.util.Collection-):

> Executes the given tasks, returning the result of one that has completed successfully (i.e., without throwing an exception), if any do before the given timeout elapses.

Use `invokeAll` if you want to wait for all submitted tasks to complete.

Use `invokeAny` if  you are looking for successful completion of one task out of N submitted tasks. In this case, tasks in progress will be cancelled if one of the tasks completes successfully.

Comment: `submit` does not "hide" an exception, it throws it wrapped in `ExecutionException` when `get` is called. The original exception can then be retrieved by `ExecutionException.getCause()`

Answer (score 10):

A main difference between the submit() and execute() method is that ExecuterService.submit()can return result of computation because it has a return type of Future, but execute() method cannot return anything because it's return type is void. The core interface in Java 1.5's Executor framework is the Executor interface which defines the execute(Runnable task) method, whose primary purpose is to separate the task from its execution.

Any task submitted to Executor can be executed by the same thread, a worker thread from a thread pool or any other thread.

On the other hand, submit() method is defined in the ExecutorService interface which is a sub-interface of Executor and adds the functionality of terminating the thread pool, along with adding submit() method which can accept a Callable task and return a result of computation.

**Similarities between the execute() and submit() as well:**

1. Both submit() and execute() methods are used to submit a task to Executor framework for asynchronous execution.
2. Both submit() and execute() can accept a Runnable task.
3. You can access submit() and execute() from the ExecutorService interface because it also extends the Executor interface which declares the execute() method.

**Apart from the fact that submit() method can return output and execute() cannot, following are other notable differences between these two key methods of Executor framework of Java 5.**

1. The submit() can accept both Runnable and Callable task but execute() can only accept the Runnable task.
2. The submit() method is declared in ExecutorService interface while execute() method is declared in the Executor interface.
3. The return type of submit() method is a Future object but return type of execute() method is void.

Answer (score 8):

If you check the source code, you will see that `submit` is sort of a wrapper on `execute`.

```
java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService#submit(java.lang.Runnable)
```

```
public Future<?> submit(Runnable task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<Void> ftask = newTaskFor(task, null);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Submit - Returns Future object, which can be used to check result of submitted task. Can be used to cancel or to check isDone etc.

Execute - doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `execute(Runnable command)` is the implemented method from Interface `Executor`. It means just execute the command and gets nothing returned.

`ExecutorService` has its own methods for starting tasks: `submit`, `invokeAny` and `invokeAll` all of which have `Callable` instances as their main targets. Though there're methods having `Runnable` as input, actulaly `Runnable` will be adapted to `Callable` in the method. why `Callable`? Because we can get a `Future<T>` result after the task is submitted.

But when you transform a `Runnable` to a `Callable`, result you get is just the value you pass:

```java
static final class RunnableAdapter<T> implements Callable<T> {
    final Runnable task;
    final T result;
    RunnableAdapter(Runnable task, T result) {
        this.task = task;
        this.result = result;
    }
    public T call() {
        task.run();
        return result;
    }
}
```

So, what's the point that we pass a `Runnable` to submit instead of just getting the result when the task is finished? Because there's a method which has only `Runnable` as parameter without a particular result.

Read the javadoc of `Future`:

> If you would like to use a Future for the sake of cancellability but not provide a usable result, you can declare types of the form Future<?> and return null as a result of the underlying task.

So, if you just want to execute a `Runnable` task without any value returned, you can use `execute()`.

if you want to run a `Callable` task, or

if you want to run a `Runnable` task with a specified result as the completion symbol, or

if you want to run a task and have the ability to cancel it,

you should use `submit()`.

Answer (score 1):

On top of previous responses, i.e.

- execute(..) runs the task and forget about it
- submit(...) returns a future;

The main advantage with the future is that you can establish a timeout. This might come very handy if you have an executor with a limited number of threads and your executions are taking forever, it will not hang the process.

Example 1: hangs forever and fills the executor

```
  ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
     executor.execute(() -> {
         while (true) {
           System.out.println("Running...")
           Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE)
         }              
     });
  }
```

Your output will be (i.e. only 2 and it gets stuck):

```
Running...
Running...
```

On the other hand, you can use submit and add a timeout:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
    Future future = executor.submit(() -> {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Running...");
            Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    });

    try {
        future.get(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (!future.isDone()) {
            System.out.println("Oops: " + e.getClass().getSimpleName());
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }
}
```

The output will look like this (notice that the executor does not get stuck, but you need to manually cancel the future):

```
Running...
Oops: TimeoutException
Running...
Oops: TimeoutException
Running...
Oops: TimeoutException
Running...
Oops: TimeoutException
Running...
Oops: TimeoutException
```

Answer (score 0):

basically both calls execute,if u want future object you shall call submit() method 
 here from the  doc

```
public <T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<T> ftask = newTaskFor(task);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}


public <T> Future<T> submit(Runnable task, T result) {
    if (task == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    RunnableFuture<T> ftask = newTaskFor(task, result);
    execute(ftask);
    return ftask;
}
```

as you can see java really has no way to start a thread other than calling run() method, IMO. since i also found that `Callable.call()` method is called inside `run()` method. hence if the object is callable it would still call `run()` method, which inturn would call `call()` method 
from doc.

```
public void run() {
    if (state != NEW ||
        !UNSAFE.compareAndSwapObject(this, runnerOffset,
                                     null, Thread.currentThread()))
        return;
    try {
        Callable<V> c = callable;
        if (c != null && state == NEW) {
            V result;
            boolean ran;
            try {
                result = c.call();
                ran = true;
            } catch (Throwable ex) {
                result = null;
                ran = false;
                setException(ex);
            }
            if (ran)
                set(result);
        }
    } finally {
        // runner must be non-null until state is settled to
        // prevent concurrent calls to run()
        runner = null;
        // state must be re-read after nulling runner to prevent
        // leaked interrupts
        int s = state;
        if (s >= INTERRUPTING)
            handlePossibleCancellationInterrupt(s);
    }
}
```