# Java Multithreading with ThreadPools loosing Tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I'm still new to the multithreading topic and am loosing tasks.

I have an application which reads as an input packets from the network interface (6400 packts per seconds). On each packet a task shall be executed which takes in average of 0.00045s. The processing time is varies and can be sometime 0,001s. When im Monitoring how often the task is executed (comparing of the counts) I notice that i'm loosing 15 Percent.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor exe;
BlockingQueue<HashMap<String,String>> packetQueue;
int count, countTh;

public MyClass(){
     this.exe = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
     this.count = 0;
     this.count = countTh;
}

public void myFunction(){
     while(true){
          HashMap<String,String> packet = new HashMap<String,String> packetQueue.take();
          count++;
          Thread th = new Thread(){
               @Override
               public void run(){
                  countTh++;
                  myTask(packet);
               }
          };
          this.exe.execute(th);                   
}
```

What I tried to fix the issue:

1. Did some simple Math to calculate how many Thread I would need and got 3 Threads. -> Still loosing Threads
2. Monitored the Threads in the ThreadPool with getActiveCount() and was very surprised that the threads were always active, never waiting
3. Monitored the ThreadPool queue with getQueue() and found out that the Queue is sometimes ob to 10k high.
4. I changed the ThreadPool to a Cached Thread Pool to monitor with how many Threads are used and it was up to 15k threads! Still it was no option to leave it like this, because it kind of destroyed the overall performance. I guess there were not enough threads left for other processes within the application

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can fix this issue? Or point me to where the issue may lay?

Comment: What syntax is `HashMap<String,String> packet = new HashMap<String,String> packetQueue.take();`? Is it compilable?

Comment: Please provide an [mcve]. This doesn't compile (see @HonzaZidek's comment), and it's hard to tell where data is coming from or how you decide that you "lose threads" - not sure what you mean by that either.

Comment: I wouldn't pass `Thread` to `execute`, rather just `exe.submit(() -> myTask(packet));`.

Comment: @Honza Zidek, so sorry! Forgot to add that it comes from blocking queue.

Comment: @daniu should I poste the whole code for the capture of the interface? I thought it may be too much. I edited how I noticed that some tasks where not executed.

Comment: Why do you create a `new HashMap` every time you take out a packet? Why do you put packets into a blocking queue in the first place, rather than immediately adding the processing task to the queue the executor service already provides? Are you only counting threads or keeping track of how many packets are processed as opposed to received?

Comment: @Kayaman omg! I sat with this problem for days! Thank you very very much! That was the key. Could you help me understand this further to why it made such a big difference? I saw some other questions here regarding sumit() and execute() (ie https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730290/what-is-the-difference-between-executorservice-submit-and-executorservice-execut) but couldn't see the relevance to my issue.

Comment: “i'm loosing 15 Percent” — Losing 15% of *what*?

Comment: It’s a huge historical design mistake that `Thread` implements the `Runnable` interface. I don’t know any place where a `Runnable` is expected and passing a `Thread` would be appropriate. The whole point of a `ThreadPoolExecutor` is that you should not deal with instances of `Thread` yourself.

Comment: If you are monitoring by observing `count` and `countTh`, don’t expect those fields to be accurate unless you make them `volatile`.  See [the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3) for an explanation.

Comment: You are conflating threads with _tasks._ A thread (represented by a `Thread` instance) is an entity that does work. A task (represented by anything that `implements Runnable`) is a piece of work that needs to be done. Don't mix them up. Like @Holger said, it's a minor tragedy that Java designers allowed you to use the same class `Thread` in either role, but if you keep those ideas separate—use `Runnable` for tasks, and only use `Thread` when you're going to call `t.start()`—then your code will be easier to read, and other developers will be more likely to want to help you with it.

Comment: @VGR even declaring the counters `volatile` will not make the `++` operator atomic, hence, does not solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments! A lot to learn for me!

Answer (score 1):

### Limit your use of expensive platform threads

Way too many threads. Generally, the rule of thumb is to limit all your active threads to less than the number of cores on the host machine. All threads used in Java 20 and earlier are “platform threads” meaning each is a wrapper around a host OS thread. Platform threads are expensive, and you should use few of them.

Do not instantiate a thread for each task. Submit your tasks as [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) to a `ExecutorService` that you instantiate once and then keep around.

### Use `ExecutorService`

Why the cast to `ThreadPoolExecutor`? Just use [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

In modern Java, we rarely need to deal explicitly with [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html). Instead of instantiating `Thread`, let an executor service manage threads on your behalf. See [Comment by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035478/java-multithreading-with-threadpools-loosing-tasks/77036111#comment135807911_77035478).

### Avoid `execute` if you want threading

The [`Executor#execute`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute(java.lang.Runnable)) method is clearly documented saying the execution may or **may not** happen on another thread. To quote the Javadoc, my emphasis:

> Executes the given command at some time in the future. The command may execute in a new thread, in a pooled thread, *or in the calling thread*, at the discretion of the Executor implementation.

So, if you want threading, use the other methods such as `submit` or `invokeAll`.

### Virtual threads

Sounds like your app is a good candidate to use the new [virtual threads](https://openjdk.org/jeps/444) feature in Java 21. With virtual threads, you can reasonably run millions of threads at a time. They are vastly cheaper than platform threads.

```
BlockingQueue < Map < String , String > > packetQueue = … ;
try (
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
) {
    while ( someCondition ) 
    {
        Map < String , String > map = packetQueue.take() ;
        Runnable task = ()->{
            myMapProcessor.process( map ) ;
        };
        executorService.submit( task ) ;
    }
}
```

### Thread-safe count of executions

As for “losing tasks”, you’ve not defined what you mean. Perhaps you mean counting each task execution.

If you want to count executions of your task method, establish an [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instance up front. [Increment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet()) that count in your executing task code. Being atomic means the count will be accurate across threads. As Commented [by VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035478/java-multithreading-with-threadpools-loosing-tasks#comment135808574_77035478) and [by Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77035478/java-multithreading-with-threadpools-loosing-tasks#comment135810317_77035478), your attempt to count executions was done incorrectly, in a manner not thread-safe. Your non-thread-safe counting may very well  account for your “losing tasks”.

```java
final AtomicLong countTaskExecutions = new AtomicLong( 0 ) ;
BlockingQueue < Map < String , String > > packetQueue = … ;
try (
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
) {
    while ( someCondition ) 
    {
        Map < String , String > map = packetQueue.take() ;
        Runnable task = ()->{
            countTaskExecutions.incrementAndGet() ;
            myMapProcessor.process( map ) ;
        };
        executorService.submit( task ) ;
    }
}
System.out.println( "countTaskExecutions = " + countTaskExecutions.get() ) ;
```

### Setting a flag across threads

Likewise, if your `someCondition` is set and accessed across threads, make it an [`AtomicBoolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicBoolean.html).

```java
final AtomicBoolean continueToProcessPackets = new AtomicBoolean( true ) ;
final AtomicLong countTaskExecutions = new AtomicLong( 0 ) ;
BlockingQueue < Map < String , String > > packetQueue = … ;
try (
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
) {
    while ( continueToProcessPackets.get() ) 
    {
        Map < String , String > map = packetQueue.take() ;
        Runnable task = ()->{
            countTaskExecutions.incrementAndGet() ;
            myMapProcessor.process( map ) ;
        };
        executorService.submit( task ) ;
    }
}
System.out.println( "countTaskExecutions = " + countTaskExecutions.get() ) ;
```

Notice how we mark the atomic variables as
`final` to ensure no other reference is substituted.

Comment: Thank you so much for your hints! I will look into each remark! wrt "losing" tasks, I just counted the incomming packets and how often the process within the Thread was called.