# How to tell a Runnable to throw an InterruptedException?

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, runnable

I'm writing a scheduler which accepts a `Runnable` which is either queued for synchronous or asynchronous execution.

I would like to be able to implement a `SomeScheduler.interrupt(int taskId)` which causes a `InterruptedException()` to be thrown from within the thread.

Is this possible or am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: i think with `sleep` method

Comment: Are you using submit() or execute()? Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342/choose-between-executorservices-submit-and-executorservices-execute/35424481#35424481. Future.get() is useful to get InterruptedExeception and take corrective action.

Answer (score 2):

`Thread`s can be interrupted, a `Runnable` is just class that implements the run method.
On it's own it doesn’t belong to a thread, if you want to interrupt the execution of the runnable you need to interrupt it's calling thread.
The typical way this is done is to use an `ExecutorService`. When you submit a runnable or callable to the executor service it will return a `Future` you can then interrupt a particular task by using the `Future#cancel` method.
Note that simply interrupting the thread doesn’t cause `InterruptedException` to be thrown unless the thread is running code that checks the interrupt status and throws `InterruptedException`, for example the `Thread#sleep` method.

Comment: but you cannot do that since runnable does not have it in it's signature

Comment: @Sarief Runnable does not have what in it's signature?

Comment: It does not have InterruptedException. Since it's checked -> you cannot add it to signature.

Comment: Ah right, I see what you mean. The InteruptedException doesn't need to bubble out of the Runnable, it just needs to stop running.
The code in the Runnable needs to either manually check the state of `Thread#interrupted()` and halt/return when it encounters it or utilise a method like `Thread#sleep` that does this automatically. Since you cant throw the exception out of the runnable, you can catch it, and either simply `return` or rethrow as a runtime exception, doesn't really matter, so long as you end the thread.

Comment: yup, but that is what OP is asking about