# When does ExcecutorService fails during execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

According to the document regarding newFixedThreadPool in Executors, I found

> If any thread terminates due to a failure during execution prior to
>   shutdown, a new one will take its place if needed to execute
>   subsequent tasks.

While I run my code, I detected my fixed sized threadPool with capacity 5 keep generating threads as time goes like `pool-1-thread-3212` which suppose to be `pool-1-thread-5 or less`

So I wonder when does ExecutorService decide one of its thread fails and launch new one.

Could anyone guide me the reason why this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you did not implement exception handling properly, thread will die depending on the way you submit the task to ExeuctorService.

Since you are using `FixedThreadPool`, fixed number of threads have to maintained in case of thread death.

if you use [execute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-) instead of [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/AbstractExecutorService.html#submit-java.lang.Runnable-), thread will die in case of unhandled exceptions.

Sample code to simulate the exception & thread death using `execute()`

import java.util.concurrent.*;

```
import java.util.*;

public class ThreadDeath{
    public ThreadDeath()
    {
        System.out.println("creating service");
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for ( int i=0; i < 5; i++){
            service.execute(new Runnable(){
                     public void run(){
                        int a=4, b = 0;
                        System.out.println("Thread Name before divide by zero:"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                        System.out.println("a and b="+a+":"+b);
                        System.out.println("a/b:"+(a/b));

                     }
                });
        }
        service.shutdown();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ThreadDeath test = new ThreadDeath();
    }
}
```

Now check the thread names in output:

```
creating service
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-1
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-2
a and b=4:0
a and b=4:0
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-3Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-2"
a and b=4:0
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-4
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" a and b=4:0java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-5
```

Now just replace `execute` with `submit` while submitting the `Runnable` task. The exception will be swallowed and output is like this: ( You can see only two threads, since FixedThreadPool size is 2)

```
creating service
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-1
a and b=4:0
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-2
a and b=4:0
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-1
a and b=4:0
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-2
Thread Name before divide by zero:pool-1-thread-1
a and b=4:0
a and b=4:0
```

For more details on Thread creation, refer to this [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.java/?v=source) link:

```
private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core)
```

Comment: this should be the answer I was looking for without question,
thx for clean & complete tips!

Comment: You can check related SE question to catch exceptions with submit() method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342/choose-between-executorservices-submit-and-executorservices-execute/35424481#35424481